# jQuery each not getting to second item in array

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure why the each iteration is not alerting `Table Two` value.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    Test1([{id:"one",tbl:"Table One"},{id:"two",tbl:"Table Two"}]);
});

function Test1(arrObj) {
                   
    $.each(arrObj,function(idx){
        var thing = $(this);
        alert(thing[idx].tbl); //Not getting to Table Two
    
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tbl' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you can see that a second argument is passed to the callback representing the value of the element.  You can use it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    Test1([{id:"one",tbl:"Table One"},{id:"two",tbl:"Table Two"}]);
});

function Test1(arrObj) {
                   
    $.each(arrObj, function(idx, thing){
        alert(thing.tbl);
    
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't wrap `this` into `$()`. Because `this` is already a value of each element of the array `arrObj`.
You can do so, and it will be enough, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ogqacm6/3/):

```
function Test1(arrObj) {

    $.each(arrObj,function(){
        alert(this.tbl);
    });
}
```